# xcode 6 upgrade causing prepare for segue lag showing screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I've developed an app in Xcode 5.1.1, targeting iOS 7. I've recently upgraded to Xcode 6 and have cleaned up everything to ensure functionality.  The only thing that is not fully working is a segue trigger post login, that is now flickering the screen of the view I'm trying to skip over. Is this a known issue? How do I get around it?  It was working fine in Xcode 5.1.1.

To recap in text, I have a Login Screen that segues to a Navigation Controller.  The first view controller in the Nav Controller is the dashboard, and the second is the welcome screen.  After they login, I am loading the Nav Controller, but skipping over the dashboard and segueing to the welcome screen auto-magically. This segue is performed in the dashboard segue code viewwillappear (see below).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.pushToHomePage)
    {
        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
        self.pushToHomePage = NO;

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"WelcomeCached"];
        [defaults setObject:nil forKey:@"WelcomeItems"];
        [defaults setObject:nil forKey:@"WelcomeSliders"];
        [defaults setObject:nil forKey:@"WelcomeEvents"];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomePageSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else if (self.pushToTradeSignals)
    {
        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
        self.pushToTradeSignals = NO;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TradeSignalsSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

        self.lblName.text = [user objectForKey:@"name"];

        PFFile *imgProf = [user objectForKey:@"ProfilePic"];
        [self.imgProfile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgProf.url]
                        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_user_icon.png"]];

        NSArray *parts = [self.lblName.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

        if (parts != nil && parts.count > 1)
            [self.lblName boldSubstring:parts[1]];

        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)
        {
            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [self setCellColor:[UIColor clearColor] ForCell:cell];
        }

        [self.navigationController.toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [self.navigationController.toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setTranslucent:NO];

        [self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                           forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                                   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]
                                       forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: There are similar reports of issues calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` from `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:`. Try calling from `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Won't viewDidAppear be called after ViewWillAppear?  I'm trying to avoid "flickering" the dashboard before transitioning to the Welcome screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. You always have to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated:]`. Omitting this call leads to undefined behavior.
2. You must not present a new screen while another screen transition is already in progress. This also leads to undefined behavior. I.e. don't present another screen inside a `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear`.

You should create the `UINavigationController` with both view controllers set at once.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up here. So I have the the Nav Controller created in the Storyboard, with both View Controllers set. How can I load this to where it starts on the second View Controller, but maintains the hierarchy inclusive of the first view controller?

Comment: I never use Storyboard so I have to speculate here: If you were able to assign both view controllers as the nav controller's root then it should start with the second screen immediately. If not then you have to instantiate the second view controller manually in code (using UIStoryboard's instantiateViewController... method) and push it without animation to the nav controller before presenting the nav controller.

Comment: In the storyboard it goes like this: Nav controller --> Dashboard (as root) --> Welcome.  The reason I have it like that is because there is a button on the Welcome screen that goes backwards in the hierarchy to the dashboard (sort of like a profile/settings screen).

Comment: Can you try to segue the dashboard to the welcome screen *before* you segue to the nav controller? If that doesn't work, push the welcome screen manually on the nav controller as mentioned above.

Comment: That did it - pushing the welcome screen manually. When using the performsegue method, it was loading the dashboard for some reason.  Thanks!